# Used XCTesting to tap on tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I'm just starting to use the new Xcode UI Testing framework introduced in Xcode 7.
I've had some issues making the 1st very simple test, and wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong.

I have a simple app with the structure:

- 1st scene a static table view, with Static Cells. Configured entirely
  in the storyboard. The only cell in this table view has a label
  'Start UI Tests'
- Selecting this links to a dynamic table view, and in
  the navigation bar is a System 'Play' button (which starts
  downloading content).

My 1st test is simply that when you select the 'Start UI Tests' cell, you move to a view that has a play button in the navigation bar.
My issue is that if I add a call to sleep(2), or add a breakpoint and stop execution **before** hitting the tap() call on the table view cell everything works as expected, the app moves to the next view, and the test succeeds, the play button is detected as being there. However if I don't add a call to sleep(2) at this point, the tap() seems to do nothing, the app does not navigate to the next view, and so the test fails as it cant find the play button (the app is still on view 1).

- Is it necessary to call sleep(2) before every cell tap action?
- Is this a bug?
- Are there any better solutions?

Code below:

```
func testExample() {

        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let tablesQuery = app.tables
        let firstCell = tablesQuery.element.cells.staticTexts["Start UI Tests"]

        sleep(2) //Only by adding in a call to sleep() before does the tap() call do anything
        firstCell.tap()

        let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
        let playButton = app.navigationBars["Live_App_Demo.UITestsTableView"].buttons["Play"]

        expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: playButton, handler: nil)
        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)

        XCTAssert(playButton.exists)
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any animations or spinners happening on the initial screen? Have you tried accessing the label directly? Try `app.staticTexts["Start UI Tests"].tap()`.

Comment: I don't have any animations / spinners, no just a static table, with hardcoded data. I do setup parse SDK in appDidFinishLaunching, with id / key, but taking this out doesn't change the result. Also, accessing the label directly doesn't change the outcome, works with sleep(), but not without this call

Comment: Can you post the example code to GitHub?

Comment: unfortunately in it's current state, the code contains keys for the company I work for that are not public, so I cant do that easily. If I get the chance to make a slimmed down version to demo the issue I will